# TSQL Using 2 tables, one with historic dates only and one with future dates

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I'm struggling to create a view to pull data from 2 tables. One is historic shelf balance data (2 years worth) and the other is the projected shelf balances. The data is weekly in both (Mondays) and the projected balances are for historical weeks and for 26 weeks in the future.

[tables and expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYDVZ.png)

table shelf_balance

```
Date      product   quantity
07/08/23  prod1     10
14/08/23  prod1     12
21/08/23  prod1     13       (current week)
```

table projected_shelf_balance

```
Date      product   proj_quantity
07/08/23  prod1     8
14/08/23  prod1     10
21/08/23  prod1     11
28/08/23  prod1     13
```

Expected output
table shelf_balance

```
Date      product   quantity  proj_quantity
07/08/23  prod1     10        8
14/08/23  prod1     12        10
21/08/23  prod1     13        11
28/08/23  prod1     NULL      13
```

Everything I've tried so far ends up with the data pulling all the columns correctly up to the current week and no further. I've tried various types of joins as well as case statements (case when table1.date IS NULL then table2.date ELSE table1.date END as week_date)
Any help with a simple solution would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance
I'm using Sql Server Management Studio v19 and an Azure Database

Comment: That you are using SSMS is irrelevant; it's just an IDE(like) application that can be used with several database products. For example, it support SQL Server, but the version you state (Version 19) supports SQL Server 2008-2022; that's 7.5 different versions. Tag the database engine you are using, not the IDE. Tagging [[tag:ssms: is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL helps to avoid misunderstandings, e.g. "dates" stored a `varchar(max)` rather than `date`. Including your attempt(s) helps us point out where you went awry. It sounds like you were close and may have just misunderstood the `join` criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
SELECT 
            ISNULL(p.[Week], h.[Week]) as [Week],    
            ISNULL(p.[Product] h.[Product]) as [Product],
            h.ShelfQty, 
            p.ProjectedShelfQty
    FROM myHistoryTable h 
        FULL JOIN myProjectionTable p 
            ON h.[Week] = p.[Week]
            and h.[Product ] p.[Product]
```

I've used FULL JOIN so that if the join fails from either table, the record will still available from the other table. Using ISNULL just gives us the week and product from the projection table if it exists, if it doesn't we use the one in the history table.

*If you need to order the results, you can either order by ordinal positions (e.g. `ORDER BY 1,2`) or you can order by the same expressions used to get the week and product, or wrap this query in another and then you can group on the resulting week and product columns.*